# Android SQlite query problem

Tags: android, sqlite, select

As the title says I am having a little trouble with a query on an sqlite database.Basically, what I am trying to do is retrieve a bunch of quotes from the database, depending on the author chosen from user in a list.

But there is a problem with my SELECT statement(it seems..), and I can't seem to spot it, so if any of you good folk could lend a pair of eyes I would really appreciate it.

My query:

```
public Cursor getQuotes(int position){

    String who = authorName[position];

    return qmDB.query(QUOTES_TABLE, new String[]{
            KEY_QUOTE
            },
            KEY_AUTHNAME + "=" + who,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}
```

Error:

04-28 20:05:10.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25017): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Anton": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT quote FROM Quotes WHERE auth_name=Robert Anton Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes around your "who" string.

Comment: However, a better way would be to use as third and fourth parameters: ... KEY_AUTHNAME + "=?", new String[] {who}, ...