# STRING in sqlite database query

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite, text

When i try to search in row POINTA (text data type in SQLite) and I compare it to a String the program stops. This is the code:

```
 public Cursor getpoints(String start,String end) throws SQLException {
   Cursor mCursor =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_PRIM, 
                NAME,
                POINTA,
                POINTA_LANG,
                POINTA_LAT,
                POINTB,
                POINTB_LANG,
                POINTB_LAT
                },
                POINTA +"=" +start,//here is the problem 

                null,
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
...
```

Comment: Are you certain _start_ is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823763/android-sqlite-query-problem/5823840#5823840), you need single quotes around your `start` String, i.e.

```
     POINTA + "='" + start + "'",
```